# Show the convergence of a sequence

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $X, Y$ are Banach spaces, $T_n: X \rightarrow Y$ are linear and continuous operators such that for all $x \in X$ we have $T_n(x) \rightarrow T(x)$. Prove that for any sequence $(x_n) \subset X$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x \in X$ we have $T_n(x_n) \rightarrow T(x)$.

I was trying to show that $\sup_{n} \|T_n\| = c < \infty$, because we would have $$\|T_n(x_n) - T(x)\| = \|T_n(x_n) - T_n(x) + T_n(x) - T(x)\| \leq \|T_n(x_n) - T_n(x)\| + \|T_n(x) - T(x)\| \leq c\|x_n - x\| + \|T_n(x) - T(x)\| \rightarrow 0$$ but I didn't manage to prove this fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Apply the uniform boundedness principle.

Comment: I don't see where we use the fact that $Y$ is a Banach space but I guess this wasn't a necessary assumption.

Comment: @tosi3k No, it's not necessary, you are right.